# how to run an application with database in c# on another computer

Tags: c#

hi please if you can help me with this problem

I have a application with database in C# and only run on the computers where I have installed Visual Studio on the other computers the app run but not find the database. The database is Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient)

in app.config i have this settings

```
<connectionStrings>

add name ="db" connectionString="Data Source= > >(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\util\service.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

the path of the database in the other computer is correct set

Comment: You need to install LocalDB on the other computer and have your database file in that location if you don't change it. LocalDB is not really meant to be used at runtime. You should prefer something like SQLExpress or higher edition. If you are thinking of a single user standalone database then using embedded SQLite or LiteDb would be a much easier solution.

Comment: thank you for your reply

Comment: You seem to ignore what I said really :) Despite you have answers all pointing to SQL Express, you really should consider using LiteDb or SQLIte for a single user standalone application.

Comment: I did not ignore your answer. At work I use a program that has the database in SQL Server Express and I think it's easier for the future if I learn to work with these databases. Anyway, thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to install visual studio on all the machines, when you build your application (in debug or release mode) you only need to copy the files in the related bin folder to the target machine. (if I understood that bit)

The config files contains the connection string to the database, in your case a local file (but will be using SQL Express) Look at creating your database in SQL Server Express and pointing to that in development. On the target machines you can then install SQL Express and use that. The connection string will be different to what you have now, look for some examples..

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the .mdf file without a SQL Server engine. It works on your Visual Studio machines, because it comes with SQL Server Express.

Answer (score 1):

LocalDB cannot be accessed remotely, as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017)

If you are going to use the same database, you probably should setup SQL Server Express on your server then update the connection string on the other machines, otherwise you will need to install LocalDB on each machine.